# Write lambda statement to select items from a list where a property of an item (enum) is found in a list of enum values?

Tags: c#, enums, lambda

I have a cache where I store `Project` objects. One property of a project is it's `ProjectState`, which can be Active, Inactive, Canceled, or Archived.

I would like to give the user an option to select a given number of project states, and then pull all of the projects that have a state in that list. For example, the list could have all four states:

```
List<ProjectState> states = new List<ProjectState>() 
{ 
   ProjectState.Active, 
   ProjectState.Inactive, 
   ProjectState.Canceled,
   ProjectState.Archived
};
```

Unfortunately, I find myself writing a condition for each and every state:

```
List<Project> myProjects = myCache.Where(p => 
   p.state == ProjectState.Active || 
   p.state == ProjectState.Inactive || 
   p.state == ProjectState.Canceled || 
   p.state == ProjectState.Archived).ToList();
```

Is there any way I can condense this statement to check if an item is in the list? While this is invalid syntax, I would like something that could do:

```
var myProjects = myCache.Where(p => p.state IN states).ToList();
```

I have found the solution, and I will answer this question to share it because I am sure I am not the first or last person to come across this type of scenario. However, is there a better solution? Is there syntax out there to check if 'an item is in a list' as opposed to 'if a list contains an item'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After racking my brain for a while and digging through documentation, I realized my logic was wrong.

I was too focused on selecting projects where the state was *in* the list, that I wanted to find syntax that matched that train of thought. However, I realized I could use the Contains() function because it is the same for me to select projects where the list *contains* the state of that project.

The solution to my problem was:

```
var myProjects = myCache.Where(p => states.Contains(p.state)).ToList();
```

Comment: Entity framework translates this query to something like `where state in (1,2,3,4)`.  I think that this is the answer and the best answer, providing your list is of a reasonable size.

Comment: @Grax thanks for sharing, I didn't know that. In my case, I will most likely never have an enum that exceeds 10 items. In your opinion, though, what would you say is 'reasonable size'?

Comment: Pretty sure that 10 would never be an issue.  I am thinking about hundreds or thousands.  Most of my uses for this clause are under 50 items, so I have never had an issue to worry about.